# What is the maximum size of SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am getting following error with `SurfaceView`

```
01-06 18:48:31.947: E/SurfaceFlinger(180): dimensions too large 5700 x 1506
```

I totally understand that this is very big `SurfaceView` and I should do a lot more refactoring in order to change my custom `View` to `SurfaceView`

But I am curious that why is it too large, can't Android allocate the `SurfaceView`? Can't it ignore drawings which is not visible in the view port? How do I know what is the maximum size of `SurfaceView` which can be used? Are there differences between the maximum size?

Thanks.

Comment: On what sized (resolution & heap memory) device/emulator are you using.

Comment: This is LG Nexus 5, real device

Comment: This could be any device with any resolution and any size SurfaceView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is coming from the lower level native code for SurfaceFlinger.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-4.4.2_r1/services/surfaceflinger/Layer.cpp

```
uint32_t const maxSurfaceDims = min(
        mFlinger->getMaxTextureSize(), mFlinger->getMaxViewportDims());

// never allow a surface larger than what our underlying GL implementation
// can handle.
if ((uint32_t(w)>maxSurfaceDims) || (uint32_t(h)>maxSurfaceDims)) {
    ALOGE("dimensions too large %u x %u", uint32_t(w), uint32_t(h));
    return BAD_VALUE;
}
```

In short you are trying to allocate a texture/viewport larger than what the OpenGL driver/GPU is configured. You already know that the request is too large. As the size is dependent on the device/manufacturer I'm not sure if you can get a definitive value which can span across the multiple vendors of Android.

You may also want to review what was done in Jelly Bean to improve UI performance which is covered in the Google IO 2012 session: [For Butter or Worse: Smooth Out Performance in Android UIs](https://developers.google.com/events/io/2012/sessions/gooio2012/109/) which should give you a high level view of what the graphics engine is trying to do.